# Wordpress loop repeats posts

Tags: wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

I have written a loop that loops through a custom post type and I need it to display them all on the page. However some of the posts at the beginning are displayed twice, not right next to each other but seemingly randomly. It only repeats a small number of posts near the beginning and I've checked in the backend that they aren't duplicate posts so I'm fairly confident it's something in the loop that is displaying them twice. Here's the code.

```
 <?php 
    $currentPage = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $args= array(
      'post_type'=>'business',
      'posts_per_page'=> -1,
      'paged'=>$currentPage,
    );

$theQuery = new WP_Query($args);
?>
    <div class="listings-header">
        <h2>Search Results</h2>                 
    </div>

    <div class="search-results grid-x grid-margin-x">

     <?php if ($theQuery->have_posts()) : while ($theQuery->have_posts()) : $theQuery->the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'parts/loop', 'archive' ); ?>

      <?php endwhile; ?>    

      <div class="pages-wrap">
        <p class="page-text">Page</p>
        <?php joints_page_navi(); ?>
      </div>

      <?php else : ?>

      <?php get_template_part( 'parts/content', 'missing' ); ?>

      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Thanks as always for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing "wp_reset_postdata()" after "endwhile;".
It is recommended to use this function after using WP_Query(), so as to refer to the $post global variable of the current post.